# XPATH target div and image in loop?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here's the document struvture:

```
<div class="search-results-container">
<div>
 <div class="feed-shared-update-v2">
   <div class="update-components-actor">
    <div class="update-components-actor__image">
     <img class="presence-entity__image" src="https://www.testimage.com/test.jpg"/>
     <span></span>
    <span>test</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="feed-shared-update-v2">
   <div class="update-components-actor">
    <div class="update-components-actor__image">
     <img class="presence-entity__image" src="https://www.testimage.com/test.jpg"/>
     <span></span>
    <span>test</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

not sure the best way to do this but hoping someone can help. I have a for loop that grabs all the divs that precede a div with class "feed-shared-update-v2". This works:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'feed-shared-update-v2')]//preceding::div[1]");
```

I then run a for loop over it:

```
for card in elements:
```

however i'm having trouble trying to target the img and the second span in these for loops. I tried:

```
for card in elements:
  profilePic = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//following::div[@class='update-components-actor']//following::img[1]").get_attribute('src')
  text = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//following::div[@class='update-components-text']//following::span[2]").text
```

but this produces a error saying:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//following::div[@class='update-components-actor']//following::img[1]"}
```

so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to what i'm doing wrong. I know its my xpath syntax and i'm not allowed to chain "followings" (although even just trying .//following doesn't work, so is ".//" not the right syntax?) but i'm not sure what the right syntax should be, especially since the span does not have a class. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are overusing the `following::` axis. Simply try the following (no pun intended):
For your first expression use

```
//*[contains(@class, 'feed-shared-update-v2')]/..
```

This will select the parent `<div>` of the `<div class="feed-shared-update-v2">`. So you will select the whole surrounding element.
To retrieve the children you want, use these XPaths: `.//img/@src` and `.//span[2]`. Full code is

```
for card in elements:
  profilePic = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img").get_attribute('src')
  text = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[2]").text
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me closer, only issue now is it just loops over the same div lol 

Thank you!

Comment: You now have a reference element: try `div/div/div/img` and `div/div/div/span[2]` in the loop. Maybe this improves things.

Comment: Good idea, wonder if its possible to reference them by the index number of "card"? Will experiment. THanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It seems in the span that there is not such class of div called: update-components-text

did you mean: *update-components-actor*?

Im not such a fan of xpath, but when i copied your html and img selector, it did find me 2 img, maybe you are not waiting for the element to load, and then it fails?
try using implicit/explicit waits in your code.

I know you are using xpath, but concider using css

This might do the trick:

```
.feed-shared-update-v2 span:nth-of-type(2)
```

And if you want a css of the img:

```
.feed-shared-update-v2 img
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this. I think my issue is getting the for loop to honor the path selector above it, which ".//" doesn't seem to work :(